# How to edit multiple post with Custom fields

Tags: custom-field, bulk

I created a custom field for my post. All sounds good except for the fact that when I try to edit multiple posts (in the same time) by selecting the multiple option in the post list, I only find some fields available and not my custom field. 
Is there a way to edit the multiple edit option for posts in order to have my custom field available too?

Comment: Have you tried this plugin first? https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-bulk-editor/ seems to do what you would like to do here.

Comment: yes i saw but didn't work... it cannot let me see my custom field into the multiple post edit option...

Comment: found a great solution with the plugin suggested: custom-field-bulk-editor. Indeed it's possible to filter posts by date, so it's that i was searching. thanks to Ahmed Mahdi for the suggestion. Case closed :)

Comment: great. remember to answer your own question with the solution and accept it.